# How to get rid of JavaScript Debugging warning in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am developing a web application using Visual Studio 2019. I am getting the below message each time when I run the application from visual studio. I know the reason is simply that there is a breakpoint somewhere in a javascript file, But I cannot find it. I cannot see any javascript file in the breakpoint window, it shows only .cs files.

[image]

[image]

This is very annoying, Is there a way to get rid of this warning? Or a way to see where exactly is the breakpoint so that I can manually delete it.

Comment: You can choose Continue Debugging(Don't Ask Again) and it will get into the file where sets breakpoint. Meanwhile you can remove it if you do not want this breakpoint.  Besides, this warning is because you set breakpoints to the js and visual studio does not allow js debugging. If you allow js debugging, the warning will disappear.

Comment: @Rena I had chosen Continue Debugging (Dont Ask Again) but it didn't got me into that file

Comment: Hi @vivek nuna, sorry my fault. Continue Debugging(Dont't Ask Again) means you will not receive such warning again and it will continue debugging without enable js debugging.

Comment: And if you choose Enable Javascript Debugging it will get into the js file. If you just want to get ride of the warning, pls chosse the Continue Debugging (Dont Ask Again)